# what is question mark means in the url in php codeigniter framework

Tags: codeigniter, url, helper

i'm beginner in php so i want to ask this question

I read about url in Codeigniter and know url is include controller name and then method name but i didn't know what's question mark means yet ?

for example

where form post data if the url after click on submit button is

```
http://localhost/code/forums/topic/25674318?addpost=Publish
```

i'm using Codigniter may i use this url to post submitted data to model i mean insert that data to database.

Answer (score 0):

This is the symbol `?` which starts the begining of query in url. And after that you can use `&` symbol

```
<?php echo $this->input->get('addpost');?>
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html?highlight=get

Or

```
<?php echo $_GET['addpost'];?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

And then should return **Publish**

The fist query in url good to have ? then any other query you can use &

Example: `http://www.demo.com/example/?token=123456&something=test`

```
$var1 = 123456;
$var2 = 'test';

site_url('example/'. '?token=' . $var1 . '&somthing=' . $var2);
```

**Config**

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-&=?';
```